# SQL Query Needs Modifying — Cannot Show Same Topic More Than Once

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table on my web site that shows the most recent posts on my phpBB forum. My query works as expected, except that I only want one result per topic.

(eg. if six people respond to a topic in succession I don't want the table filled with that one topic; I only want the most recent result from that topic + five others).

As it currently stands if I post a reply in a topic the topic will appear at the top of the table. If someone else, Mr. X say, replies to my post, the same topic will appear in the list above mine, with a link to my response + a link to his response. I want his response (being more recent than mine) to replace the listing for the same topic in that table (if that makes any sense).

---

```
 mysql_query(" SELECT phpbb_posts.post_id, 
               phpbb_posts.post_time, 
               phpbb_posts.topic_id, 
               phpbb_posts.forum_id, 
               phpbb_posts.poster_id, 
               phpbb_topics.topic_id, 
               phpbb_topics.topic_title, 
               phpbb_users.user_id, 
               phpbb_users.username, 
               phpbb_users.user_avatar, 
               phpbb_users.user_avatar_type 
        FROM   phpbb_posts, 
               phpbb_topics, 
               phpbb_users 
        WHERE  ( phpbb_posts.poster_id = phpbb_users.user_id ) && ( 
                      phpbb_posts.topic_id = phpbb_topics.topic_id ) && ( 
                      phpbb_posts.forum_id != 21 ) && ( phpbb_posts.forum_id != 23 ) 
        ORDER  BY phpbb_posts.post_time DESC 
        LIMIT  0, 6 ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_time, p.topic_id, p.forum_id, p.poster_id, 
       pt.topic_id, pt.topic_title, pu.user_id, pu.username, 
       pu.user_avatar, pu.user_avatar_type 
FROM phpbb_posts p
INNER JOIN (SELECT topic_id, MAX(post_time) post_time FROM phpbb_posts GROUP BY topic_id) A ON p.topic_id= A.topic_id AND p.post_time = A.post_time 
INNER JOIN phpbb_topics pt ON p.topic_id = pt.topic_id
INNER JOIN phpbb_users pu ON p.poster_id = pu.user_id
WHERE p.forum_id NOT IN (21, 23)
ORDER BY p.post_time DESC 
LIMIT  0, 6;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.post_time, p.topic_id, p.forum_id, p.poster_id, 
       pt.topic_id, pt.topic_title, pu.user_id, pu.username, 
       pu.user_avatar, pu.user_avatar_type 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts p ORDER BY p.topic_id, p.post_time DESC) AS A GROUP BY topic_id) AS p
INNER JOIN phpbb_topics pt ON p.topic_id = pt.topic_id
INNER JOIN phpbb_users pu ON p.poster_id = pu.user_id
WHERE p.forum_id NOT IN (21, 23)
ORDER BY p.post_time DESC 
LIMIT  0, 6;
```

Comment: Hi Saharsh. I've inserted your code but unfortunately I'm still getting the same results (ie. duplicates where the forum's two most recent posts are in the same topic)